# Set ApplicationData folder on app.config and get it on Nlog.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, app-config, nlog, nlog.config

I'd like to set the path of NLog log file on app.config.

I know how to set the applicationData folder on NLog.config. It's like that:

```xml
<target xsi:type="File" 
    name="logFileCsv" 
    fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/something/something.log">
```

And if I use the NLog.Extended I know how to get key values from app.config and use them on NLog.config, like that:

```xml
<target xsi:type="File" name="logFileCsv" fileName="${appsetting:name=LogPath">
```

And on app.config should be like this

```xml
<add key="LogPath" value="${APPDATA}/something/something.log" />
```

But it's not working the way I want. NLog is creating the log file on `c:\..\${APPDATA}/something/something.log"`

So, I'd like to know how to set the ApplicationData folder on app.config to be understandable by NLog?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `${appsetting}` won't evaluate the value.

As work around you can do:

```xml
<target fileName="${APPDATA}/${appsetting:name=LogPath}" />
```

note: wrapping in a ${replace} also won't work

Answer (score 1):

I tried the [answer of Julian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54652088/2561753), but it wasn't utterly successful:

`Error FileTarget(Name=logFileCsv): Failed write to file '\\something\something.log`

However, with that help and workaround, I figure out how to do it:
So in App.config just add the final path:

```xml
<add key="LogPath" value="\something\something.log"/>
```

and in NLog.Config I did this:

```xml
<target xsi:type="File" name="logFileCsv" fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/${appsetting:name=LogPath}">
```

And now the log is written on the right path: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\something\something.log